# Bootstrap datepicker maxdate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

jQuery:

```js
$("#min").datepicker({maxDate: 0, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
$("#max").datepicker({maxDate: 0, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="from" id="min">
<span class="input-group-addon"> to </span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="to" id="max">
```

Anyone can please tell me Why this not working and How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In this below example will help you here I have changed `maxDate:0` to `startDate:01/10/2018` and `endDate:02/10/2018` so your max date will be `feb 10 2018`

```js
$("#min").datepicker({ startDate: "01/10/2018",
endDate: "02/10/2018", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
$("#max").datepicker({ startDate: "01/10/2018",
endDate: "02/10/2018", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="from" id="min">
<span class="input-group-addon"> to </span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="to" id="max">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet. Added validations as well.

```js
function populateEndDate() {
  var date2 = $('#max').datepicker('getDate');
  date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
  $('#max').datepicker('setDate', date2);
  $("#max").datepicker("option", "minDate", date2);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#min").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    minDate: 'dateToday',
    onSelect: function(date) {
      populateEndDate();
    }
  }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
  $('#max').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    minDate: 1,
    onClose: function() {
      var dt1 = $('#min').datepicker('getDate');
      var dt2 = $('#max').datepicker('getDate');
      if (dt2 <= dt1) {
        var minDate = $('#max').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
        $('#max').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
      }
    }
  }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<label for="">start</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="min" name="start">
<label for="">end</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="max" name="end">
```